# Documentation tool for Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, documentation

Does anyone know of a documentation tool for Google Apps Script? I understand that GAS is something that is not written on the client-side but an online documentation tool would be a fine option? Any thoughts and help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A automatically generated documentation feature is included to GAS. [Here](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.de/2012/05/introducing-versions-and-libraries-in.html) is an article describing how to use it in libraries (the `Writing a Library` paragraph).

Comment: Thank you. I think libraries should do. Will have to dig in further though.